# finding unique web links using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program to extract unique web links from www.stevens.edu( it is an assignment ) but there is one problem. My program is working and extracting links for all sites except www.stevens.edu for which i am getting output as 'none'. I am very frustrated with this and need help.i am using this url for testing - http://www.stevens.edu/

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = raw_input('enter - ')

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = bs (html)

tags = soup ('a')

for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href',None)
```

please guide me here and let me know why it is not working with www.stevens.edu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site check the `User-Agent` header, and returns different html base on it.

You need to set `User-Agent` header to get proper html:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = raw_input('enter - ')
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # <--
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
soup = bs(html)
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href', None)
```